# How to execute a callback with custom arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, callback, arguments

Is there a way in JS to execute a callback with custom argument(s) rather than no argument(s) at all, for example:

```
btn.onclick = displayText
```

**OR**

```
operation.onComplete(displayText)
```

Here, I want the callback `displayText` to be called with an argument like `displayText("Hello World")` rather than the default `displayText()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the call of `displayText` with a function declaration as follow:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
    displayText(myCustomText);
}
```

```js
var myCustomText = "Hello World ";
var myCustomText2 = "from Ele!";

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {
  displayText(myCustomText, myCustomText2); // Here you can pass the custom params.
};

function displayText() {
  console.log(arguments);
}
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
```

Adopt the function `addEventListener` to bind events.

```js
var myCustomText = "Hello World ";
var myCustomText2 = "from Ele!";
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  displayText(myCustomText, myCustomText2); // Here you can pass the custom params.
});

function displayText() {
  console.log(arguments);
}
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` or `call` to invoke the method with arguments.

```
btn.onclick = function() {
    displayText.call(null, "Hello World", arg1, arg2...);
}

btn.onclick = function() {
    displayText.apply(null, ["Hello World", arg1, arg2, ...]);
}

function displayText(arg1) {
   console.log(arg1);
}
```

Comment: Why not only `displayText("Hello World");`?

Comment: `displayText("Hello World")` invokes the function immediately. If I am not wrong, we are just associating a call back in the example above.

Comment: In the 2nd case, does it mean that I can pass **multiple arguments** to the function `displayText`?

Comment: @MelvinAbraham That is correct, `call` takes comma separated list of arguments. `apply` takes in a single argument which is an array of args

Comment: It's totally unnecessary the usage of `apply` and `call`.

Comment: @Ele true. the function can be invoked without any operator.